# token code error

Tags: solidity, remix

my code has an error please help
the problem part:

```
constructor() public { 
    _name = (PITCROIN);
    _decimals = (2);
    _totalSupply = (100);
    _balances[msg.sender] = _totalSupply;

    emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, _totalSupply);
```

the error:

```
DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
   --> readfbtbvd.sol:352:14:
    |
352 |     _name = (PITCROIN);
    |              ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Why are you putting parentheses everywhere?

Answer (score 2):

The name is of type `string` so you have to put it in quotes like so:

```
constructor() public { 
    _name = "PITCROIN";
    _decimals = 2;
    _totalSupply = 100;
    _balances[msg.sender] = _totalSupply;

    emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, _totalSupply);
```

Also there is no need for parentheses.